# Elasticsearch sorting by array column

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, elasticsearch

How to sort records by column with array of numbers?
For example:

```
[1, 32, 26, 16]
[1, 32, 10, 1500]
[1, 32, 1,  16]
[1, 32, 2,  17]
```

The result that is to be expected:

```
[1, 32, 1,  16]
[1, 32, 2,  17]
[1, 32, 10, 1500]
[1, 32, 26, 16]
```

Elasticsearch has sort mode option: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_option. But no one variant is not appropriated.

Language Ruby can sort arrays of numbers' array, ruby has method [Array.<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), which description says "*Each object in each array is compared*"

How to do the same with elasticsearch?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

In ElasticSearch [arrays of objects do not work as you would expect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html):

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
>   each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
>   need to be able to do this then you should use the [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype
>   instead of the [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) datatype.
>
> This is explained in more detail in [Nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype.

It is not possible to access array elements at sort time by their indices since they are stored in a Lucene index, which allows basically only `set` operations ("give docs that have array element = x" or "give docs that do not have array element = x").

However, by default the initial JSON document inserted into the index is stored on the disk and is available for scripting access in the field [`_source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-source-field.html).

You have two options:

1. use [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)
2. store value for sorting explicitly as string

Let's discuss these options in a bit more detail.

#### 1. Script based sorting

The first option is more like a hack. Let's assume you have a mapping like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_array": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can achieve intended behavior with a scripted sort:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
      "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script" : "String s = ''; for(int i = 0; i < params._source.my_array.length; ++i) {s += params._source.my_array[i] + ','}  s",
            "type" : "string",
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

(I tested the code on ElasticSearch 5.4, I believe there should be something equivalent for the earlier versions. Please consult relevant documentation in the case you need info for earlier versions, like for [1.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/modules-scripting.html).)

The output will be:

```
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "my_array": [
            1,
            32,
            1,
            16
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "1,32,1,16,"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "my_array": [
            1,
            32,
            10,
            1500
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "1,32,10,1500,"
        ]
      }
    ]   }
```

Note that this solution will be slow and memory consuming since it will have to read `_source` for all documents under sort from disk and to load them into memory.

#### 2. Denormalization

Storing the value for sorting explicitly as string is more like ElasticSearch approach, which favors [denormalization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html). Here the idea would be to do the concatenation before inserting the document into the index and use robust sorting by a string field.

Please select the solution more appropriate for your needs.

Hope that helps!